# Retrieving Sitecore attachments/files via API

Tags: sitecore-api

I’m a newbie to Sitecore. My client is using Sitecore as a document storage tool to store files in form of pdf, word, etc. The requirement is to fetch the files through Sitecore’s API from an external system.

I have looked at ItemService REST API to retrieve items but haven’t yet come across an endpoint to access files. Can someone please help me on how to go about solutioning this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the item Api will download files. Just returned Sitecore field values. You will probably have to make your own MVC Api and download it that way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321628/how-to-download-media-library-images-from-sitecore-to-local-folder

Comment: You can try search provider like Solr to query documents and get document details in custom web API. Anyd custom webspi helps you to download file

Comment: Presuming the files are in the media library, there should be a direct URL to each item as though you were downloading it via the website... why not just call the item's URL directly?